# how to update element within div tag

Tags: jquery, append

I want to change:

```
<div class="control-group">
```

to:

```
<div class="control-group success">
```

I do not how to update the element within the div tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a specific method for that, the [.addClass(](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)) method:

```
$('.control-group').addClass('success');
```

Other methods that can be of some interrest here:

- [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not how to update the element within the div tag.

First, You have a terminology problem here, this is not an *element*, but rather an *attribute* of an element that you want to update. Read here about the `class` attribute: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/class

Second, in order to add another css `class` to your `div` element, you should update it's `class` attribute. You can use jQuery in order to achieve it:

```
$('.control-group').addClass('success');
```

Or to append it using pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('yourDivId').className += ' success';
```

With this example, just make sure to set the Id attribute in your `div`.